# Disable chrome extension warning

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Whenever I start chrome I get a warning popup to disable my custom (local) extensions. Is there a way to prevent this nagging?

I mean apart from me having to pay Google to upload my extensions to their webstore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up

Comment: @Jedi https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates